# How to know if all fragments were detached?

Tags: android, android-fragments

On my app I am using a Main Activity, which has a Navigation Drawer, and as the user go to an options from the drawer, it will change the fragment beging displayed accordingly to the option selected.

If the user hit's "Back button" several times, it will go back to a point in which it will reach my Main Activity, which is a blank and empty layout.

When I reach this point (my main activit, empty), I would like to exit the app, or, open the Navigation Drawer.

The problem is, I don't know any event that shows me that I am back to the Main Activity. I checked the onResume, but it's never called, which makes sense, since the main activity has never been stopped.

I thought perhaps there would be an event from the fragment manager that would be called on the Main Activity when a fragment was detached, and from there I could check if there was no fragment at all attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push your first fragment, add a tag to it. Something like

```
transaction.replace( R.id.rootContainer, firstFragment, "rootFragment");
```

Whenever user presses back button, you can get your rootFragment from FragmentManager

```
FirstFragment myFragment = (FirstFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("rootFragment");
```

And check if this  fragment is visible or not, by `myFragment.isVisible()`, if not, then keep popping the stack, if it is visible, it means user is on the first fragment. Now you can either quit the app, or show your menu drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Good night good sir. Thank you for your tip.
I used a different approach, based on your repply, that gave me quite a few insights.

On main activity, I Overrided the onKeyDown and check if it was pressed the Back Button. If yes, then I check the size of my Back Stack.

Uppon that, I decide if I want to finish my application.

Also, thanks for the tip of "labeling" the fragments on the back stack, didn't know I could do that.